# Mac Bash - doesn't recognize if[$#=0]

Tags: macos, bash, shell, if-statement, square-bracket

It's been a while since I've scripted in bash so I made a small script to test things out. This is my script (the quoted text is some Dutch, doesnt really matter):

```
#isingelogd
if[$#=0]
then
    echo "Geef user-id's op!" 1>$2 ; exit 1
fi
for uid in $*
do
    if who|grep $uid >dev/null
    then
            echo $uid is ingelogd
    else
            echo $uid is niet ingelogd
    fi
done
```

If I try to run it it tells me the following:

```
bash-3.2$ ./isingelogd
./isingelogd
./isingelogd: line 3: if[0=0]: command not found
./isingelogd: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./isingelogd: line 4: `then'
```

If I check my version with bash -v I'm running 3.2 which I thought supported square brackets.

Has someone had a similar problem and found solution?

Comment: I think that should be `if [ $# -eq 0 ]`. `=` is string comparison, as explained [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: The square brackets are not mere syntax, `[` is actually a shell command. Like any command, it needs spaces after it to separate it form its arguments (similarly, `if` needs a space after it). The `[` works differently based on how many arguments it receives (its last argument must be `]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your errors:

> bash-3.2$ ./isingelogd
>   ./isingelogd
>   ./isingelogd: line 3: ***if[0=0]: command not found***
>   ./isingelogd: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
>
>   ./isingelogd: line 4:`then'

See that *command not found*? you have an error in your script.

The `[`..`]` are actual commands, and like all commands, they need to be separated by white spaces. The `=` is a parameter to the `[` command and also needs to be surrounded by white space. Change line #3 to this:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
```

Since `$#` and `0` are numeric, you should use `-eq` which compares to numbers and not `=` which compares strings.

Try these commands:

```
$ ls -li /bin/test
$ ls -li /bin/[
```

You'll see they have the same inode number. They're links. (Yes, the `[` and `test` are builtins into the shell, but they are linked builtin commands).

```
$ man test
```

will give you all of the various *tests* that `[` can do. Again, note the difference between `-eq` vs. `=` and `-gt` vs. `>`.

Note the following:

```
if [ 54 > 123 ]
then
    echo "54 is greater than 123"
fi
```

This will print out "*54 is greater than 123*". This won't:

```
if [ 54 -gt 123 ]
then
   echo "54 is greater than 123"
fi
```

Comment: what is the difference betwen -eq vs. = and -gt vs. >?

Comment: Thx so much :)
It's working now, forgot about the importance of whitespace.

Thank you all for a very clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

`a.bash` works for me in Mac. Content of `a.bash` is the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage da da do" 
fi

export A=$1
echo $A
```

then execute with the following :

```
\# ] ./a.bash

   Usage da da do
```